# sscanf() double showing zeros

Tags: c, scanf

I'm having troubles with sscanf() function to read doubles. I have a comma separated text file like this:

```
ABC,DEF,0.465798,0.754314
GHI,JKL,0.784613,0.135264
MNO,OPQ,0.489614,0.745812
etc.
```

So first I get the line with fgets() and then I use sscanf() to get the two string and two double variables.

```
fgets(buffer, 28, file);
sscanf(buffer, "%4[^,],%4[^,],%lf[^,],%lf[^\n]", string1, string2, &double1, &double2);

printf("%s %s %f %f\n", string1, string2, double1, double2);
```

But the output is:

```
ABC DEF 0.465798 0.000000
GHI JKL 0.784613 0.000000
MNO OPQ 0.489614 0.000000
```

So somehow it doesn't scan the last float. I've tried `%lf[^ \t\n\r\v\f,]` and just `%lf` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why not use the much simple format string `"%3s,%3s,%lf,%lf"`?

Comment: Change `"%4[^,],%4[^,],%lf[^,],%lf[^\n]"` to `"%4[^,],%4[^,],%lf,%lf"`

Comment: You're not showing your real code (you'd need to pass &double1 and &double2 into sscanf). Cut and paste your actual code and then we might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks chux, it worked, I tought I should use the [^,] also with doubles because I don't have spaces. I had the "&" signs (edited the code now) when I asked the question, it was a typo, sorry about that.

Comment: Since the `[^,]` did not begin with a `%`, sscanf() was looking for the 4 letters exactly in the input string.  Failing to find those, the scan stopped, leaving `double2` to its previous value.  Hence the importance of checking the sscanf() result.  Who knows what evil data come in from files and stdin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
"%4[^,],%4[^,],%lf[^,],%lf[^\n]"
```

To

```
int result;
result = sscanf(buffer, "%4[^,],%4[^,],%lf,%lf", string1, string2, &double1, &double2);
if (result != 4) // handle error
```

Notice the `&` on `double1` and `double2` - likley a typo.

Also **strongly** recommend to check that the result is 4.  Not checking the `sscanf()` result is really core to this question.  The "zeros" printed out are the result of `double2` not having been scanned and retained its previous value which could have been anything.  Had the `sscanf()` result been checked it would have reported 3, showing the problem was between scanning `double1` and `double2`.  But in the larger scene, it is good practice to verify *all* the expected values were scanned before going on.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your variables `double1` and `double2` are pointers, you will get undefined behavior.

You need to use the address-of operator `&` to get a pointer to those variables:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%3s,%3s,%lf,%lf", string1, string2, &double1, &double2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sscanf(buffer, "%4[^,],%4[^,],%lf[^,],%lf[^\n]", string1, string2, double1, double2);
```

should be

```
sscanf(buffer, "%3s,%3s,%lf,%lf", string1, string2, &double1, &double2);
```

Note `&` (address of) for doubles

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your code didn't work is because:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%4[^,],%4[^,],%lf[^,],%lf[^\n]", string1, string2, &double1, &double2);
```

`%[...]` and `%[^...]` are actually conversion types, like `%d`, `%x`, and they match/don't match sequence of listed characters, ending with `]`. Notice that you don't have to provide `%s`, even though you're parsing string.

Your problem was that you combined two type of conversion types, `%lf` and `[^...]`, scanf actually sees the later part as the string to match, so for instance following code would successfully parse the string:

```
char *b = "ABC,DEF,0.465798[^,],0.754314[^\n]\n";
sscanf(b, "%4[^,],%4[^,],%lf[^,],%lf[^\n]", string1, string2, &double1, &double2);
```

The easiest solution is to leave `[^,]` part (chux's solution):

```
sscanf(b, "%4[^,],%4[^,],%lf,%lf", string1, string2, &double1, &double2);
```

Or use field width (Joachim Pileborg, and David RF's solution):

```
sscanf(buffer, "%3s,%3s,%lf,%lf", string1, string2, &double1, &double2);
```